# Random IE11 crash on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, crash, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I've experienced a random crash from IE11 on Windows 8.1, which appears to be related to BEX64 and MSHTML.dll but I'm not sure how to diagnose and/or fix it.

Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: How often does this happen? From what I understand from your question is that this only happened once. I wouldn't bother if so, crashes just happen. If it happens often like once per week, then there might be help for you.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid It only happened once but I was just curious about what could've triggered. Does Event Viewer provide more information or does it provide the same information as the Reliability Monitor?

Comment: Eventviewer will have more raw data which could help, so yes it probably does.

Comment: Well, the exception code in Event Viewer's log is 0xc0000409. Googling it suggests it's a STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN.

Comment: create a crash dump (http://pastebin.com/SxrK4LWY), zip and upload the dmp so that I can take a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

Removing KB4022168 from my computer window 7 worked for me.
try this and se if its working on window 8.1.
Thanks

Comment: `KB4022168 ` was released on June 27th 2017.  This was a full 28 months after this question was asked.  Additionally, the patch you have mentioned, doesn't even apply to Windows 8.1.  This does not answer the author's question.  Consider modifying your answer to provide specifics, on how the author's resolves their problem.